# Best practices for saving settings?

Tags: java, application-settings

I am currently working on a project in which many options should be saved.

- How are options normally saved?
- What are best practices when saving/loading settings?

Comment: You should try a .ini file.
But I don't think this is a SO question.

Comment: what do you mean by settings??is it user preferences?? what are your thoughts?? Please try something before you post here.

Comment: save it in properties-files.

Comment: What sort of 'settings' are they?  Most of the answers offered really only cater for `String` based key/value pairs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Preferences API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/overview.html) for this if it is user specific configuration that should be stored and maintained.

> Applications require preference and configuration data to adapt to the needs of different users and environments. The java.util.prefs package provides a way for applications to store and retrieve user and system preference and configuration data. The data is stored persistently in an implementation-dependent backing store. There are two separate trees of preference nodes, one for user preferences and one for system preferences.

Comment: What is the difference between the Preferences and Properties?

Comment: When using Preferences you don't have to care about where the data is stored. On Windows it is stored in the Registry for example.

Answer (score 6):

You could use `.properties` files to store configurations, usually those are used to store environment configurations. If this is what you're talking about.

Have a look at the [documentation about that](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html); also this could be an example

```
String path = servletContext.getRealPath(propertiesFilePath);            
Properties prop = new Properties();         
try {           
    prop.load(new FileInputStream(path));
} catch (Exception e) { 
    // handle      
}     
String name = prop.getProperty("name");
```

Comment: You're welcome, remember to later accept the answer that got you to the proper direction.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend using java properties. Properties are configuration values managed as key/value pairs. It is possible to load/save properties from your program or edit the `*.properties` configuration files manually.

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html)

[Example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples)

I hope this is what you call "settings"..